# Frequency of an DatetimeIndex is sometimes connected to the frequency of the copied DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, copy

I have an experiment where I want to copy a DataFrame and change the frequency of the DatatimeIndex.
I found out that the original DataFrame also changes the frequency if no changes are applied to the DatetimeIndex of the copy. If I apply some changes the copy, the frequency of the original stays the same.

**Experiment 1**

```python
import pandas as pd
dr = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=10, freq='1H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'target':list(range(10))}, index=dr)
dfc = df.copy()

# dfc.index += pd.Timedelta('1h')
dfc.index.freq = None

print(df.index.freq) 
>>> None
print(dfc.index.freq)
>>> None
```

By the way `df is dfc` returns `False`, that indicates, that this are two seperate objects.

**Experiment 2**

```python
import pandas as pd
dr = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=10, freq='1H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'target':list(range(10))}, index=dr)
dfc = df.copy()

dfc.index += pd.Timedelta('1h') # commented
dfc.index.freq = None

print(df.index.freq) 
>>> <Hour>
print(dfc.index.freq)
>>> None
```

My expectation is, that it should make no difference if I apply changes to the DatetimeIndex of the copy or not.

How to explain this behavoir? Is this intended?

This is done in python 3.9.7 and pandas 1.3.3.

Comment: Interesting question! My guess: The difference between the two experiments is that the first doesn't change the underlying `np.ndarray` while the second does (check the `id(df(c).index.array)`s during the experiments). Since an `Index` is immutable, the second experiment has to create a new one. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html): _"While Index objects are copied when deep=True, the underlying numpy array is not copied for performance reasons. Since Index is immutable, the underlying data can be safely shared and a copy is not needed."_

Comment: This is a good explanation, but it feels strange to me, but maby this is only my usecase. To make it work, `dfc.index = copy.deepcopy(df.index)` is one solution.

Comment: I understand your unease. I'm still mulling over why it is possible to change the `freq` attribute, without creating a new object - given that the Index is immutable. The change of `freq` doesn't have any impact on the actual data, okay. But nevertheless, immutuabilty should go further.

Comment: Do you think this is an issue which should be addressed on GitHub? Is it worth a ticket?

Comment: I don't have any experience with raising issues there, so I don't know. But it seems to me worth a shot.